# Integrating minimum of two periodic functions

Tags: calculus

I am trying to see what is the simplest way to calculate the definite integral of a function of the form

$$f(x) = \min(\sin(x), \sin(2x))$$

I can of course check when $\sin(x)<\sin(2x)$ and combine the definite integrals for each section. I can imagine how I would do this when $x$ is in units of $2\pi$, as I can just multiply the result for the first period. But let's say $x=6.5\pi$, would the correct approach be to have the simplified calculation for the first $6\pi$ and then for the remaining section separately?

Comment: Visualisation: [$f$ is periodic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yq1fmblwsa) with period $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Use the fact that
$$
\begin{align}\min(\sin(x),\sin(2x))&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(x)+\sin(2x)-|\sin(x)-\sin(2x)|\right).
\end{align}$$
Hence if we integrate over a period,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\min(\sin(x),\sin(2x))\,dx&=
  -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(x)-\sin(2x)|\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi}|\sin(x)-\sin(2x)|\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/3}(\sin(x)-\sin(2x))\,dx\\
&\quad-\int_{\pi/3}^\pi(\sin(x)-\sin(2x))\,dx
\end{align}$$

Comment: That the absolute value of sin(x) can be integrated more simply? I thought this was just passing the problem on to somewhere else, but you're right this way it simplifies the integration because I can use sgn() instead.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sin2x-\sin x=2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac{3x}2$$

As the $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$

we can safely focus on $0\le x\le2\pi$ where $\sin\dfrac x2\not<0$

$f(x)$ will be $>0$

if $\cos\dfrac{3x}2>0$

$(i)0<\dfrac{3x}2<\dfrac\pi2$ or  $(ii)\dfrac{3\pi}2<\dfrac{3x}2<2\pi$

$(i)0<x<\dfrac\pi3$ or  $(ii)\pi<x<\dfrac{4\pi}3$

Consequently, $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}$min$(\sin x,\sin2x)\ dx$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/3}\sin x\ dx+\int_{\pi/3}^\pi\sin2x\ dx+\int_\pi^{4\pi/3}\sin x\ dx+\int_{4\pi/3}^{2\pi }\sin2x\ dx=?$$